# What does Controls.Add() do in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

What exactly does this code do in c# winforms, can you give me detailed explanation on how it works? What is Controls in this statement.

```
Controls.Add(btn);
```

Comment: The explanation would be the exact same as the english text shown in this code snippet, what is unclear?

Answer (score 3):

Controls is an instance of `Control.ControlCollection` class, which represents a collection of Control objects, Inheritance hierarchy is

> System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection

Note:

The Add, Remove, and RemoveAt methods enable you to add and remove individual controls from the collection. You can also use the AddRange or Clear methods to add or remove all the controls from the collection.

You can determine if a Control is a member of the collection by passing the control into the Contains method. To get the index value of the location of a Control in the collection, pass the control into the IndexOf method. The collection can be copied into an array by calling the CopyTo method.

Example of removing control from the collection using one of it's method.

```
// Remove the RadioButton control if it exists. 
private void removeButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   if(panel1.Controls.Contains(removeButton))
   {
      panel1.Controls.Remove(removeButton);
   }
}
```

Refer [Control.ControlCollection Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Control represents a collection of controls for the Form.
The code adds the control named btn to the form.

However, I would recommend not adding controls dynamically unless you have to.  Most controls should be added during the initialization of the form object.

Comment: Every control has a Controls collection and adding to it is a perfectly normal thing.